# I need to list professors that only have a certain monthly salary, but order by their annual salary

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query,

```
SELECT pr_id, pr_name, pr_date_hired, pr_title, pr_college, pr_salary
  FROM professor 
 WHERE pr_college NOT IN ('Education' ,'Social Sciences')
   AND (pr_salary/12 BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000)
 ORDER BY pr_salary DESC;
```

I figured it out, thanks guys!
I had to do the division in the where statement so that I could order by the annual salary instead of a monthly salary.

EDIT: I changed it to 12*5000 and 12*8000 and it gave the same answer as pr_salary/12

Comment: So what's the problem? You know how to use `WHERE` to perform filtering. What's stopping you from adding the filter you need? (BTW, ordering by monthly salary and ordering by yearly salary produces exactly the same results.)

Comment: You're confused. Ordering by the calculated monthly salary will be in the same order as the annual salary. Think about it. Do the math yourself. Use three people, with 36,000, 24,000, and 12,000 as their annual salaries. Then divide by 12 to get 3,000, 2,000 and 1,000 per month. Order both of the lists by salary, and they'll be in the **exact same order**.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to do `pr_salary BETWEEN 12*5000 AND 12*8000` instead of `pr_salary/12 BETWEEN 5000 AND 8000`, because Oracle wouldn't be able to use indexes if the `pr_salary` column is indexed if you multiply/divide/etc. indexed column

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you can use a outer query or the expression itself and  filter accordingly like

```
SELECT pr_id, pr_name, pr_date_hired, 
pr_title, pr_college, pr_salary/12 as computed_salary
FROM professor 
WHERE pr_college NOT IN ('Education' ,'Social Sciences')
AND pr_salary/12 = <some_value_you_want_to_filter>
ORDER BY pr_salary DESC;
```

Comment: Need to order by annual salary, not sure how to do that when I've computed a monthly salary.

Comment: @Deniz, see the posted query in answer you are ordering by salary column `ORDER BY pr_salary DESC`